# SAS code for solving dynamic non-linear models

Tags: sas, models

Could anyone suggest some SAS code to solve a small non-linear dynamic model? The model endogenous variables are: 
log(consumption)
log(investment)
log(price level)
short term interest rate
long term interest rate
output.
I have tried to use the proc model but I'm having convergence problems due to the fact that the output identity is in level terms and the equations for the demand components are in log terms.

thank you

===========

thank you everybody for the answers/comments. The code I'm using for the estimation is:

```
proc model outmodel=fair_model;
  var py rs delta_log_e rb log_pm ys DUM1997 e rs_us pop py_us y i t c x im stat;
  parms c0-c3 i0-i2 p0-p4 r0-r4 b0-b4 e0-e3;
  eq.Consumption = c0 + c1*lag(log(c/pop)) + c2*rb + c3*log(y/pop) - log(c/pop);
  eq.Investment  = i0 + i1*lag(log(i/y)) + i2*rb - log(i/y);
  eq.Price       = p0 + p1*lag(log(py)) + p2*log_pm + p3*(y/ys-1) + p4*t - log(py);
  eq.Interest_Rate = r0 + r1*lag(rs) + r2*((py-lag4(py))/lag4(py)) + r3*(y/ys-1) + r4*DUM1997  - rs;
  eq.Int_Rate = b0 + b1*(lag1(rb)- lag2(rs)) + b2*(rs-lag2(rs)) + b3*(lag1(rs)- lag2(rs)) +b4*(lag2(rs)) - rb;
  eq.Exchange_Rate  =  e0 + e1*lag(delta_log_e) + e2*(log(py/py_us)-log(lag(e))) + e3*(log((1+rs/100)/(1+rs_us/100))) - delta_log_e;
  eq.income = c + i + g + x - im + stat - y;
run;

quit;
```

*Fitting the data with the model, getting the estimates;

```
proc model model=fair_model outmodel=fair_model;
    fit Consumption Investment Price Interest_Rate Int_Rate Exchange_Rate/data=fair2 outest=outest2 n2sls;
    instruments log_pm del_y del_py g x im del_log_i;
run;

quit;
```

and then just using the solve command for solving the model and running simulations. One problem appears to be related to the income identity that is specified in levels while the other equation are specified in log terms. I have tried to respecified the c and i in the income equation as exp(log(c)) and exp(log(i)) and even tried to used an approximated income identity in log terms but it has not helped with the convergence issue. Any further thought would be much appreciated.

Comment: It might be due to me not having any knowledge of SAS that I don't get your question.

Comment: Can you provide some example code what you tried so far?

Comment: Are you using the DYNAMIC option on the FIT statement?  If not, you could try that.  I believe that PROC NLIN in SAS/STAT is also able to fit this type of model.

Answer (score 0):

`PROC MODEL` from SAS/ETS handles dynamic non-linear systems. Try doing a log transform on the variable `output` if you are having convergence issues. In addition, consider how your equations relate to each other. Below is just a hypothetical, but be sure that you are using the right fitting method. Are they SUR models, or do they need 2SLS? Could FIML be a good method to fit it? If ITOLS is not working, you'll want to reconsider the model structure and how you go about fitting it.

```
proc model data=have;
    endo log_consumption log_investment 
         log_price_level short_term_int 
         long_term_int log_output;

    log_consumption = int1 + b1*log_investment b2*log_price_level + b3*short_term_int;

    log_investment = int2 + b3*log_consumption + b4*log_price_level;

    <other models>;

    log_output = int6 + b20*log_consumption + b21*log_price_level + b22*short_term_int;

    fit / FIML;
    solve / dynamic;
run;
```